# i2c level shifting mosfet

Tags: i2c

I've looked at articles detailing I2C level shifting and referencing the below figure I have a question.
[image]

If the gates of the FETs were driven by 2.5V and everything else remained the same, would the level shifting still work?

I would think a low from the 3.3V side would propagate but a low from the 5V would not get through.

At what low-side voltage or gate voltage would this circuit not work?

thanks

Comment: Did you notice the body diodes of the FETs?

Answer (score 2):

The FETs activate when their gate voltage, relative to the source, is sufficiently above the gate threshold voltage. (The threshold voltage is specified for a very small drain current, such as 250 µA; here, we need more current for the pull-up resistors. The gate voltage we want is the one for which the datasheet specifies R<sub>DS(on)</sub>.)

The low-voltage side can activate the FETs by driving low the source.

The high-voltage side can activate the FETs by driving low the source *through the body diode*, which adds about 0.7 V.

So this circuit will work with a gate voltage of 2.5 V as long as the FETs fully switch on at 1.8 V.